# Blog listing not showing dates for every post and arrow missing off image

Tags: php, css

I am trying to get the blog to appear the same as in the first post but for some reason the date disappears and so does the arrow on top of the image.

You can view my site [here](http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/blog/).

The current code:

```
<style>

    #title_wrapper {
        width: 488px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-familly: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
        line-height: 16px;
        display: inline;
        padding: 2px;
    }

    #dateinfo {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    #gonnaBeOnTheBottom {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 5px;
    }

</style>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">
    <?php if(is_front_page()) {
        get_template_part('featured-content');
    } ?>

    <div class="full-width page-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <h1>Blog</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row  show-for-medium-up">
        <div class="column breadcrumb">
            <?php if(function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb')) {
                //echo __('Home',TD) . ' > ';
                yoast_breadcrumb('<span id="breadcrumbs">', '</span>');
            } ?>

            <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display_list_multidim_children')) { ?>
                <ul class="breadcrumbs">
                    <?php bcn_display_list_multidim_children(); ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>

            <span style="float:right;">
                    <a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" title="RSS 2.0 Feed"><img
                            src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/rssfeed.png" width="image_width"
                            height="image_height" alt="RSS 2 Feed"/></a>
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I actually had issues with this fairly recently.

Ultimately, I learned that by default, `the_date()` will only display the date for the **first post** on a given day.

If you are using `the_date` you need to replace it with something else. I usually just use `echo get_the_date()`.